# Vertica - join 2 tables with Column A and approximate dateTime

Tags: mysql, datetime, join, vertica

```
TABLE1
ID  COL1 DATE
1   AA   2013-01-01 00:10:21
2   BB   2013-01-02 01:10:23
3   VV   2013-02-01 13:11:21
1   SD   2013-02-11 10:13:33
2   BB   2013-01-02 09:10:23
1   CC   2013-01-01 10:10:21
3   VV   2013-02-01 19:11:21

TABLE2
ID1  COL2 DATE1
1   A2A   2013-01-01 08:20:21
2   BDB   2013-01-02 01:30:23
3   V4V   2013-02-01 13:31:21
```

The result should be

```
ID  DATE 
1   2013-01-01 10:10:21
2   2013-01-02 01:10:23
3   2013-02-01 13:11:21
```

My query:

```
SELECT B.ID,B.DATE
FROM TABLE1 B 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 A 
ON B.ID=A.ID1
AND to_char(B.DATE,'YYYY-MM-YY') = to_char(A.DATE1,'YYYY-MM-YY');
```

Result I am looking for B.ID=A.ID1 and B.DATE should be closest interval to A.DATE1

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why two databases are tagged?

Comment: Also can you clarify what does it mean _should be closest_? How close it should be? 1 sec, 2 sec, 10 sec, 1 min?

Comment: It should be 2 hours. I am looking for something like this B.DATE = (A.DATE1 - interval 2 hours)

Answer (score 1):

Question isn't clear, but desired output in HP Vertica you can get with a next query:

```
daniel=> \p
SELECT B.ID,
       B.DATE
FROM TABLE1 B INNER JOIN TABLE2 A ON
        B.ID = A.ID1
           AND
        B.DATE < A.DATE1;

daniel=> \g
 ID |        DATE
----+---------------------
  1 | 2013-01-01 00:10:21
  2 | 2013-01-02 01:10:23
  3 | 2013-02-01 13:11:21
(3 rows)
```

**UPDATE**

> I am looking for something like this `B.DATE = (A.DATE1 - interval 2 hours)`

Output isn't match a problem definition.
Lets check what is a diff between timestamps:

```
daniel=> \p
SELECT B.ID,
       B.DATE,
       B.DATE - A.DATE1 AS DATE_DIFF,
       DECODE(B.DATE - A.DATE1 <= INTERVAL '02:00:00', 1, 'MATCH', 'NOT MATCH') AS MATCH
FROM TABLE1 B INNER JOIN TABLE2 A ON
        B.ID = A.ID1;

daniel=> \g
 ID |        DATE         |  DATE_DIFF  |   MATCH
----+---------------------+-------------+-----------
  1 | 2013-01-01 00:10:21 | -08:10      | MATCH
  1 | 2013-01-01 10:10:21 | 01:50       | MATCH
  1 | 2013-02-11 10:13:33 | 41 01:53:12 | NOT MATCH
  2 | 2013-01-02 01:10:23 | -00:20      | MATCH
  2 | 2013-01-02 09:10:23 | 07:40       | NOT MATCH
  3 | 2013-02-01 13:11:21 | -00:20      | MATCH
  3 | 2013-02-01 19:11:21 | 05:40       | NOT MATCH
(7 rows)
```

So output by definition will be:

```
daniel=> SELECT B.ID,
daniel->        B.DATE
daniel-> FROM TABLE1 B INNER JOIN TABLE2 A
daniel->        ON B.ID = A.ID1
daniel->        AND B.DATE - A.DATE1 <= INTERVAL '02:00:00';
 ID |        DATE     
----+---------------------
  1 | 2013-01-01 00:10:21
  1 | 2013-01-01 10:10:21
  2 | 2013-01-02 01:10:23
  3 | 2013-02-01 13:11:21
(4 rows)
```

cheers ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just to clarify again, I am not looking for B.DATE < A.DATE1.                                                                                                          I am looking for something like this B.DATE = (A.DATE1 - interval 2 hours)      Hope this clarifies.

Comment: @SKumar I updated my answer, but it still isn't clear. Can you improve your question?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the update. I am not able able to vote up, but this is what I am looking for. Thanks again @sKwa

Comment: @SKumar You are welcome, I'm glad I was able to help. So do you accepts my answer? -http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow